# How to remove adobe reader

Tags: wine

The first time I installed Adobe Reader, I wasn't satisfied, so I wanted to upgrade to new version. I don't remember which method I used to remove the first time. Then I did install Adobe Reader 11 , but it wasn't perfectly working in my Ubuntu using Wine so I removed it. Only then I realized that the first Adobe Reader installed wasn't removed completely.

Again I installed Adobe Reader 9 from the Software Center. It works good, but the problem is I cannot open .pdf files directly, I have to select the second adobe reader in right click menu to open it. How can I remove the first Adobe Reader completely?

Comment: You'd better use Document Viewer from Ubuntu. But if your choice is Adobe Reader, you should set up default viewer for PDF files as `wine path_to_AR file.pdf`. This is done in document properties or inside the context menu -> open in...

Answer (score 2):

Search for **WINE** on Dash home. Then you will find a software named **Uninstall Wine Software**. Open the software and you'll find all of your wine software there. Then simply uninstall it.